# Компиляция JIT в библиотеке numba

Tags: python, оптимизация, jit, numba

Есть некоторый код, который считает число Пи.

```
@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def calc(iter_count):
    result = 1
    for i in numba.prange(1, iter_count):
        result += ((-1)**i)/(2*i+1)
    return result
```

Возможно ли вынести компиляцию, когда программа только запускается, а не во время первого вызова метода `calc()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выдержка из [документации](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html):

> While Numba’s main use case is Just-in-Time compilation, it also
> provides a facility for Ahead-of-Time compilation (AOT).
>
> Benefits
>
> - AOT compilation produces a compiled extension module which does not depend on Numba: you can distribute the module on machines which do
>   not have Numba installed (but Numpy is required).
> - There is no compilation overhead at runtime (but see the @jit cache option), nor any overhead of importing Numba.
>
> Limitations
>
> 1. AOT compilation only allows for regular functions, not ufuncs.
> 2. You have to specify function signatures explicitly.
> 3. Each exported function can have only one signature (but you can export several different signatures under different names).
> 4. AOT compilation produces generic code for your CPU’s architectural family (for example “x86-64”), while JIT compilation produces code
>    optimized for your particular CPU model.